# pentaho Error 64k limit in JSON FileInput

Tags: pentaho, kettle

[image]I created a job which extracts json datas from a webservice. It works on my PC but not when I export it on my dev. server (Ubuntu Server x64). please help me on this.

ERROR

> "Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Encountered
>   code generation error while compiling script: generated bytecode for
>   method exceeds 64K limit. (#1)"

JSON format

"[{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": xxxxx
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "xxx xxx-xxxx"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "xxx xxx-xxxx"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "david",
    "age": 28,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "23 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": xxxxx
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "xxx xxx-xxxx"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "xxx xxx-xxxx"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "firstName": "Jondy",
    "lastName": "rodes",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "Kenucky",
        "state": "KY",
        "postalCode": xxxxx
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "xxx xxx-xxxx"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "xxx xxx-xxxx"
        }
    ]
}]"

Answer (score 1):

See this forum post here:

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?89304-Job-runs-fine-in-Spoon-but-not-in-Kettle-Exceeds-64K-in-Json-Input-step

The suggestion seems to be to use the javascript step then turn off the optimisation option.

Comment: I am not using any javascript in the that particular transformation. just getting JSON array and putting it into database thats it .

Comment: Post a pic of your transformation.  How are you getting the json?  In order to be getting that error you must be using a step which uses an underlying javascript library..

Comment: I have posted the pic. I assume large size file will also create this problem. please correct me

Comment: ok so you are using JSON input which means it is using javascript under the hood. So read the link I posted above, do it in javascript instead, or find another way. (perhaps with one of the http / webservice get steps) At the same time raise a jira and say it should be possible to turn off optimisation in this step.

Comment: Thank you codek for your response. I need another clarification. I have attached the JSON array. I want to known how to process those JSON array by using js step and JSON input steps. can you plz give me the example

Comment: I'd post that as a new question, as it is not related to your original question and the SO police will shoot us!

Answer (score 1):

64k limit problem with jvm lower versions. Upgrade your java to 1.7 version. Problem will be solve.